# Still getting data on Google Analytics after changing domain

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

it's a weird question.

Here is a wordpress website whose original url is `https://funXXX.com`

I made a new website for displaying products which use the url `https://funXXX.com`

And the original web is changed to be a store web and change its new url is `https://store.funXXX.com`

A weird thing happened,

The dashboard is still showing infomation... and track the traffic of `https://store.funXXX.com`

There is also conversion rate.

However, in the setting page of GA, the url is still the old one `https://funXXX.com`

How I set GA for my new website?

I know the whole thing is really weird, I will keep editting and replying if someone is helping me. Thanks!

Comment: Different websites should have different tracking codes. Create another tracking code for the new site and change the embed code to the correct code. The name you assign the tracking codes in GA don't limit the code to the domain.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or maybe https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The URL you enter in the view settings **has no influence** on the data collected in Analytics (it is only used to preview pages, but on a practical level it has no impact).

If you want to limit the data to a specific domain you need to apply a **filter** based hostname to the view.